# Possible bug involving derivative of BesselI

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 12.0 or earlier. Fixed in 13.2 or earlier.**

---

In Mathematica 12.0, I run the following code:

```
f[x_] = BesselI[0, x];
f'[x]
```

which returns `BesselI[1, x]` as expected. But if I enter

```
f[x_] = BesselI[0, 1.0 x];
f'[x]
```

I get

```
0.5 (BesselI[1, 1. x] + BesselI[1, 1. System`Private`DerivativeX[1.]])
```

Moreover, `D[f[x],x]` returns the expected result. I have tried quitting the kernel with no change. Is this a bug, or is something messed up with my installation?

Comment: Looks like a bug when using inexact arguments and the shorten form `f'[x]` to me.

Comment: It works OK if you type `D[f[x], x]` instead of `f'[x]` Not sure why. could be a bug.

Comment: No problem like this in `Mathematica 11.2`. Nonetheless defining symbolic functions with approximate numbers (`1.0`) is unreasonable. Another problem  is that one should define functions with `SetDelayed` i.e. (`:=`) rather than with `Set`  i.e. (`=`). Regardless of unreasonable definitions of special functions this is a problematic issue and should be communicated to Wolfram Research Inc.

Comment: @Artes - I do not agree that "defining symbolic functions with approximate numbers is unreasonable." While you might not write `1.0 x`, it is reasonable to expect `BesselI[0, a x]` where `a` is given an inexact value. In version 12, any inexact value for `a` produces the behavior shown in the OP.

Comment: @BobHanlon  While I find your argument reasonable I insist that defining special functions with inexact numbers is simply looking for problems. That is what I've meant by "unreasonable". I don't expect Mathematica to work fine whenever one defines any rubbish functions.

Comment: Both inexact numbers and `Set` in definitions of special functions is just a "bad approach" even though it would be nicer if there were no such weak points.

Comment: I agree with both Bob and Artes here. Both make good points. But Mathematica should also do more type checking of its arguments. May be issue a warning that inexact number is detected with special function for example when exact is expected. I think Mathematica in general still does not do very good type checking on input to its functions. See for example, the code xzczd found in here https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53557093#53557093  where  `LaplaceTransform[Sin[1], 1, 1]` is accepted with no error and it returns `1/2` !

Comment: Can someone add a bug version header for this question?

Answer (score 6):

A fix is to give `` System`Private`DerivativeX `` the `NHoldAll` attribute (which it probably should have, since it seems to be used as a dummy indexed variable):

```
SetAttributes[System`Private`DerivativeX, NHoldAll]

f[x_] = BesselI[0, 1.0 x];
f'[x]
(*  1. BesselI[1, 1. x]  *)
```

Comment: Interestingly, this also works fine if you use anonymous functions: `g = BesselI[0, 1.*#] &; g'[x]`. It also works fine if the `0` is anything other than `0` e.g. `f[x_] := BesselI[a, 1.*x]; f'[x] /. a -> 0`

Answer (score 5):

Fixed in 12.1

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[f, x];
f[x_] = BesselI[0, 1.0 x];
```